# R cell selection using apply

Tags: r, matrix, cell, apply

i'm trying to select specific cell from a matrix (data) a change the value to 1

i got those 2 vector

```
data <- matrix(0,300,300)
X <- c(1,5,87,987,67)
Y <- c(5,7,12,456,99)
```

x1 and y1 (i.e 1,5) indicate the position i want to select in my matrix

I dont want to select (x1,y2)

I have done what i want to do with:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  data[x[i],y[i]]<-1
}
```

i'm pretty sure i can do the same thing with apply which could work faster

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi, yes thanks you, cbind(X,Y) working perfectly well.  I didnt know this trick

Comment: Thanks i didn't know i could mark the answer as solver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cbind` `X` and `Y` and assign the value

```
data[cbind(X, Y)]  <- 1

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

**data**

Using smaller dataset

```
X <- c(1,3,4)
Y <- c(2,3,4)
data <- matrix(0, ncol = 5, nrow = 5)

data
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```